# Downloading web content from bash/curl to python

Tags: python, bash, mechanize

I wrote a bash script to download content of some webpage. To make it work I need to catch a cookie, then send some special data request and then i am able to get to proper link to download its content.
My script look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
for ((i=1;i<=$NB;++i)); do  
cookie=`curl -I "http://example.com/index.php" | grep Set-Cookie: | awk '{print $2}' |         cut -d ';' -f 1\`  # cath a cookie  
curl -b $cookie --data "a_piece_of_data" "http://example.com/index.php"  
curl -b $cookie "http://example.com/proper_link_$i" &> $i.html  
sleep 3  
done
```

As i need to parse it later on to get rid of all html/xhtml tags ( just extract pure text ) and then convert it to XML i find out Python and its lib's will be just perfect to do that.
So I ask you for hints how to rewrite my script to python?
Here is what i come up with so far, but its still is far away from my bash example :

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

request = mechanize.Request("http://example.com/index.php")
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
cj = mechanize.CookieJar()
cj.extract_cookies(response, request)
print cj
```

Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: If you are already familiar with *cURL*, maybe it will be easier to use the [pycurl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl2/7.20.0.a1) module.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
r = session.get('http://example.com/index.php')
# session.cookies now contains any relevant cookies which will be
# used in following requests of the session
page = session.get('http://example.com/your_other_page')
```

Then use `lxml` to parse your HTML:

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Comment: thnx mate, sure ill try this, but how about sending extra package of data ??